# Mercurial - log the command executed

Tags: version-control, mercurial

We've been using mercurial for a while now and everything is working fine.

The only problem we encounter is when someone runs a "bad command".

An example would be, merging an unstable branch in the stable trunk or pulling a similarly named branch over something completely unrelated overwriting a bunch of stuff...

You've got hg log but you always get people that won't believe the output saying "I didn't do that"...now in the interest of public shaming :) and giving rightful priviledges to the "You broke the built hat", I'm wondering, is there a way to have Mercurial log every command its given to a text file that would give us something like:

```
hg pull -b something
hg merge TotallyWrongBranch
hg ci -m "I didn't do it!" -u bsimpson
```

Comment: Well, you could always shame them by running a ``history | less`` while you wait for an answer.

Comment: That would work but it's time consuming especially if the commit statement is cryptic you 're left comparing a lot of rev number.  But yeah it can work :)

Comment: You could add logging features in your central repository hooks. Like `mercurial-server` does

Comment: Btw, it is really terrible to work with such a colleagues... :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had a few minutes on my hand so I wrote an exe and named it hg.exe and renamed Mercurial's original exe to real_hg...

An ugly hack don't mind the code quality please IT WORKS!

```
public static StreamWriter sw;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    sw = new StreamWriter("hgCommandLog.txt", true);
    StringBuilder sbArguments = new StringBuilder();
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            sbArguments.Append(args[i]);
            sbArguments.Append(" ");
        }
    }
    //Console.WriteLine("arg:" + sbArguments.ToString());
    //Console.WriteLine("Session ID = " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId.ToString());
    //Console.WriteLine("hello ->"+Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME"));

    string sessionID = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId.ToString();
    string clientName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME");

    //log the command to sw
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\t" + clientName + "("+sessionID+")\t" + "hg " + sbArguments.ToString()); 
    sw.Flush();

    // Start the child process.
    Process p = new Process();
    // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "real_hg";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = sbArguments.ToString();

    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.ErrorDataReceived += outputReceived;
    p.OutputDataReceived += outputReceived;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    p.Start();
    // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
    // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    //p.BeginErrorReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();

    sw.Close();
}

static void outputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  sw.WriteLine("\t"+e.Data);
  Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

Comment: If your co-developers are so badly disciplined that they won't own up to mistakes they do, what makes you think they would want to run a mercurial "version" that logs every command they do? Also, this won't log anything if you use TortoiseHg.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: doesn't thg use regular hg.exe?

Comment: For many functions it talks directly to the Python code, to avoid the overhead of spinning up a secondary Python interpreter. Remember that TortoiseHg is written in Python as well.

Comment: What are you doing if your co-worker in questions says: *"Hey, your logging tool must be buggy. It says I did X but I never did something like that, really."* Compare the amount of work **you** have with enforcing this logging and the real benefits it provides.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen they would need to know what tortoiseHg is for that and it's not installed on the central server.  Really I just started searching for that after spending some time wondering how the unstable branch got pushed to our main trunk and how on earth did the person merging not notice.  Of course I agree with you this shouldn't be needed but...